# Find least connected sub-graphs

Tags: graphs

For example the nodes in this graph should be separated into two groups (A,B,C) and (D,E,F,G).

By looking at a graph of citations, assuming that most citations are papers from the same field, can we separate papers into fields?

[image]

Comment: Don't you mean "most connected"? The least-connected subgraphs would be independent sets. You probably want to look at something like [clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering_coefficient) but, since that's a whole field of study, I think your question is too broad at the moment. Now that you know the keyword, I suggest you do some research on your own -- we'd be happy to help with more specific questions that you might have then.

Comment: What I meant was those subgraphs least connected to the rest of the graph.

Comment: It might be a good idea to look into clustering or graph partitioning, starting from say Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

You could define what "least connected" means (precisely) in a variety of ways, where the precise definition chosen may affect the output of the algorithm (and there is no unique correct definition for this). But you may wish to look into [Community Detection algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_structure). The general intuition of Community Detection is to find a set of sub-graphs that maximises the ratio of edges within the sub-graphs versus edges between sub-graphs. Depending on the precise definition, this may be a difficult (NP-complete) problem, and so various algorithms rather use approximate (heuristic or greedy) approaches.

[Five popular Community Detection algorithms are described here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_structure#Algorithms_for_finding_communities) and should be a good starting point for your work.